# Wordpress shows homepage (200) instead of 404 in > third url segment

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I'm currently running into a strange problem with Wordpress on my production server. When I try to visit non-existing URLs, Wordpress doesn't trigger a 404 when the url has more than 3 segments, for example:

These pages don't exists and trigger a 404 page:

- http://example.com/9
- http://example.com/9/9

These also dont exist, but don't trigger a 404 page and show the homepage (with 200 response code):

- http://example.com/9/9/9
- http://example.com/9/9/9/9
- http://example.com/9/9/9/9/9

On my local machine all above pages show a 404 (as expected). The server (and my local machine) are both running nginx >10.16, both nginx vhost configs are almost equal. Running PHP72-fpm.

Debugging I already did:

- Disable functions.php in theme folder
- Disable all plugins
- Switch to other theme
- Disable cloudflare caching
- Flush permalinks

All without any success unfortunately.. I'm kinda running out of options for debugging, I hope anyone has got any suggestions!

Comment: Have you tried generating the permalinks again?

Comment: @KelvinMariano Sorry, yes I have done that already. Will add to my post. Thanks tho

Comment: This problem occurs on all wp when there is a page that contains a child page. This is a standard wp problem. you may want to open a direct ticket in wordpress. in posts this happens too?

Comment: @KelvinMariano I'm not sure if this is a bug/problem in Wordpress. The problem only persists on the production server, not on my local machine. On my local machine all the URLs throw a 404 error (which is good).

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that locally I'm running PHP73, on the production server PHP72. I've just upgraded the production server from PHP72 to PHP73 and the problem seems to be fixed!